# Nutch / Solr - Document contains at least one immense term in field="content"

Tags: solr, nutch

While crawling, we faced this issue when parsing huge PDFs. The error thrown is as per shown in the screenshot.

[image]

I tried changing the type of "content" to "text_general" or "string" but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when dealing with PDFs and OCRs there is a good chance of this happening since the text extraction is automated inside Nutch (using Apache Tika) I would suggest to use `solr.TruncateTokenFilterFactory` it is available since Solr 4.8 and will truncate any token to a specific length.

```
<filter class="solr.TruncateTokenFilterFactory" prefixLength="5"/>
```

In your case pick a large enough value that should not affect the rest of the tokens extracted from your text.

On the other hand it would be better just to ignore this token if you are able to do so, in that case use the `solr.LengthFilterFactory`:

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="3" max="7"/>
</analyzer>
```

In this case if any tokens falls out of the `[3,7]` range will be discarded.